How to remove a specific TF message in the rosbag file?
I created a rosbag file in the humble of ros2.
But I want to remove a specific message of /tf topic from the bag file.
Want to remove follow message all in /tf topic.
---
transforms:
- header:
    stamp:
      sec: 1717488269
      nanosec: 960184673
    frame_id: map
  child_frame_id: odom
  transform:
    translation:
      x: 5.0151540233755165
      y: 6.113474824976279
      z: 0.0
    rotation:
      x: -0.0
      y: -0.0
      z: 0.03264448679236415
      w: 0.999467026710768
---

Please give me some advice.
Thank you.

rosbag records all messages from the specified topics. If you want to filter messages from a recorded topic, you'll need some post-processing script.
Be sure to filter the topic(s) you want to record. ROS2 Bag Record Documentation
